# Validating the form and password-hash in php

Tags: php, validation, hash

I have a problem with my validation and password-hash sign up.

The problem is that I created a validation and it works, and then I created the password-hash section and it works too... BUT now the Validation doesnt work.

It seems like it skips the validation and saves the info in the database and hash the password. 
How can I do so the validation and hashing the password and saving the information in the database works?

I dont know how to explain more but if you dont understand or need more info tell me.

The user insert the information in the form and then it goes to the validation and go thru validation, if there is no errors in the validation it goes to the try/catch and insert the information into the database and "hash" the password.

The two parts (validation and insert into database with hash password) works perfectly separatly, but when I have the 2 parts together the validation doesnt work, it skips it.

The html-form

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
                                <table>
                                    <tr><td>
                                        <label for="fullname">Fullname<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                        </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="fullname" value="<? echo $fullname ?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $fullnameErr; ?></span>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                        <label for="email">Email<span class="req">*</span></label></td>
                                    <td><input type="email" name="email" value="<? echo $email ?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                        <label for="user">Username<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                        </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="user" value="<? echo $user ?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $userErr; ?></span>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                        <label for="pass">Password</label><span class="req">*</span</td>
                                        <td><input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" value=""><span class="error"><?php echo $passErr; ?></span>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                        <label for="rePass">Re-Password</label><span class="req">*</span</td>
                                        <td><input id="rePass" name="rePass" type="password" value=""><span class="error"><?php echo $rePassErr; ?></span>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
                                        </td></tr>   
                                </table>
                            </form>
```

And here is the php validation and saving into the database with hashed password.

```
    <?php
    $fullname = $user = $email = $pass = $rePass = "" ;
    $fullnameErr = $userErr = $emailErr = $passErr = $rePassErr = "";
?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        $fullname = trim($_POST["fullname"]);
            $email  = trim($_POST["email"]);
            $user   = trim($_POST["user"]);
            $pass   = trim($_POST["pass"]);
            $rePass = trim($_POST["rePass"]);

            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z ]*$/", $fullname)) {
                $fullnameErr = "Only letters are allowed"; 
            }
            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/",$user)) {
                $userErr = "Only letters and numbers are allowed"; 
            }
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
            }
            if (!strlen($pass) > 8) {
                $passErr = "Password at least 8 characters";
            }

            if (empty($_POST["fullname"])) {
                $fullnameErr = "Fullname is required";
            }
            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
            } 
            if (empty($_POST["user"])) {
                $userErr = "Username is required";
            }
            if (empty($_POST["pass"])) {
                $passErr = "Password is required";
            }
            if (empty($_POST["rePass"])) {
                $rePassErr = "re-enter password is required";
            }
            if ($_POST["rePass"] != $_POST["pass"]) {
                $rePassErr = "The re-entered password don't match";
            }

        try{            
            require_once("db_connect.php"); 

            $options = [
            'cost' => 12,
            ];

            $hashedPass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

            $query  = "INSERT INTO users (fullname, email, user, pass) ";
            $query .= "VALUES (:fullname, :email, :user, :pass)";
            $ps = $db->prepare($query);

            $result = $ps->execute(
                array(
                    'fullname' => $fullname,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'user'  => $user,
                    'pass'  => $hashedPass
                ));

            if($result){
                header("Location: index.php?signup=true");
            }else { 
                echo "Signup failed";                           
            }

        }catch(Exception $exception) {
            echo "Query failed, see below: <br><br>";
            echo $exception."<br /><br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well you code collects errors, but it does not do anything with this errors. It just stores the values regardless whether there are any errors.

Comment: @martinstoeckli , yes that was the problem, but i find a solution, by adding the " if(empty($fullnameErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($userErr) && empty($passErr) &&  empty($rePassErr)) {" before the try/catch and close it after that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some way to stop execution of the script if one of your validation fails.

For example

```
if (empty($_POST["user"])) {
    $userErr = "Username is required";
    return $userErr;
}
```

Otherwise it will keep running and the hashing and database insertion will happen regardless of whether the validation fails.

Comment: Yes i have it, in the html form, after the "span class error".

Comment: calling "echo" won't stop the execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer hehe.. But i will post it so you can see if someone has the same problem..

```
 if(empty($fullnameErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($userErr) && empty($passErr) &&  empty($rePassErr)) { THE CODE OF TRY/CATCH }

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        $fullname = trim($_POST["fullname"]);
            $email  = trim($_POST["email"]);
            $user   = trim($_POST["user"]);
            $pass   = trim($_POST["pass"]);
            $rePass = trim($_POST["rePass"]);

            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z ]*$/", $fullname)) {
                $fullnameErr = "Only letters are allowed"; 
            }
            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/",$user)) {
                $userErr = "Only letters and numbers are allowed"; 
            }
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
            }
            if (!strlen($pass) > 8) {
                $passErr = "Password at least 8 characters";
            }

            if (empty($_POST["fullname"])) {
                $fullnameErr = "Fullname is required";
            }
            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
            } 
            if (empty($_POST["user"])) {
                $userErr = "Username is required";
            }
            if (empty($_POST["pass"])) {
                $passErr = "Password is required";
            }
            if (empty($_POST["rePass"])) {
                $rePassErr = "re-enter password is required";
            }
            if ($_POST["rePass"] != $_POST["pass"]) {
                $rePassErr = "The re-entered password don't match";
            }

        if(empty($fullnameErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($userErr) && empty($passErr) &&  empty($rePassErr)) {

        try{            
            require_once("db_connect.php"); 

            $options = [
            'cost' => 12,
            ];

            $hashedPass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

            $query  = "INSERT INTO users (fullname, email, user, pass) ";
            $query .= "VALUES (:fullname, :email, :user, :pass)";
            $ps = $db->prepare($query);

            $result = $ps->execute(
                array(
                    'fullname' => $fullname,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'user'  => $user,
                    'pass'  => $hashedPass
                ));

            if($result){
                header("Location: index.php?signup=true");
            }else { 
                echo "Signup failed";                           
            }

        }catch(Exception $exception) {
            echo "Query failed, see below: <br><br>";
            echo $exception."<br /><br />";
        }
      }
    }
?>
```